# Does Apple Pay allow a method of authorizing the user once for multiple future payments?

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet

I have a service (iOS app) that works by letting users use a real-world service many times, but each time it's impossible to know the cost of each 'session' up front.

I'm aware that Apple Pay allows for a single checkout with an unknown amount (will be shown as 'pending'), but does Apple Pay also support a method where the user can 'authorize' an app once for (many) future update checkouts, without the user having to manually accept them each time?

Comment: Does your service use in-app purchases, or general credit card payments (through a payment service provider)?

Comment: I don't believe that you can ask the user to authorise future, unspecified amounts. You can reheat regular, fixed payments (a subscription) or irregular, balance based top-up fixed payments but you cannot have permission to bill their card whenever and for however much you want. You will need the purchaser to specifically authorise payment each time.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is impossible. Same as with credit card

Comment: I don't think so. In the credit card world, it is possible. It's called "Card on File". This is e.g. how your purchase of an app in the App Store is charged to your credit card linked to your iCloud account.